# Saving and restoring javascript objects without JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, object, canvas

I have a page on a site I'm working on, the page is called 'create.php'. It allows users to create javascript objects called 'entities' on HTML5 canvas via mouse-click. I would like the created entities to be saved to a mysql database and then be recreated on another page of the site, that page is called 'restore.php'. It is important for the site to save and restore the javascript entities, not merely the canvas state, so canvas save() and restore() are not options. The system I have so far is respresented in the link below:

http://codepen.io/Tejay/pen/yDxFu

As you can see, I'm able to save and restore entities on the 'create' page just fine. However, the site requires that the entities be saved on a mysql database and recreated on a restore page. I'm having a problem recreating the entities on restore.php.
I convert each entity into a serialized object, push it to an array, this array is then inserted into mysql as a text type(I have also tried blob with no success)on create.php:

```
saveToStore = function(serializedEntities) {
    var save = confirm("Are you sure you want to save this canvas to the database?");
        if(save == true) {
            store = serializedEntities;
            window.location.href="save_canvas.php?store=" +store;
    }
};
```

The serialized object array is then inserted into mysql on save_canvas.php:

```
$canvas = $_GET['store'];
function save_canvas($canvas) {
    if(isset($_GET['store'])) {
        $canvas = $_GET['store'];

        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO canvas (canvas_id, canvas_array) VALUES ('','$canvas')");
    }
}

save_canvas($canvas);
```

The array is then retrieved on restore.php, the javascript code on retore.php is almost identical to that of create.php with the exception of passing the php $store variable to javascript as such:

```
<?php $store = $data['canvas_array']; ?>

<script>
var store = '<?php echo $store; ?>';
createFromStore = function() {
    if(store.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0;i<store.length;i++)
            addEntity(store[i]);
    }
}
else {
alert('nothing in store');
}
};

createFromStore(store);
</script>
```

Storing a serialized array to mysql returns [object Object]. For debugging purposes I stored the object array using JSON.stringify, retrieved it on restore.php and printed out its contents fine. Unfortunately, due to circular references, JSON is not an option. I feel like I'm not passing the stored array to the createFromStore correctly, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Your "serializeEntities" function just looks like it makes an alternative data structure. To "serialize" something means basically to turn it into a string. Can you not JSON.stringify the result of your not-quite-serilization routine?

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. If you're talking about something like this: window.location.href = "save_game.php?store=" + JSON.stringify(store); on create.php. Then on restore.php: var store = JSON.parse('<?php echo $store; ?>');  Tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" - how? what goes wrong? what does the URL look like? Are there errors in the browser console or on the server?

Comment: OK, I updated my codepen example to print out whats in the store variable, I use JSON here: http://codepen.io/Tejay/pen/yDxFu. When using JSON to stringify store as in my previous comment, the URL is like what's in display store. However, it won't recreate the boxes on canvas. I'm not sure how to pass the store variable to my createEntities function on restore.php. Or even if that's what the issue is. No errors, the createEntity function doesn't alert "nothing in store", and if I echo store it displays all the contents as in the display-store button on create.php

Comment: OK, after some more debugging, I'm not sure it's a JSON mysql issue anymore. I seem to be able to store the array and retrieve it on restore.php just fine, the issue is recreating the stored array on canvas. The problem lies in my createFromStore function on restore.php. Console says: Uncaught ReferenceError: addEntity is not defined. I'm calling createFromStore onload. I'm stuck as to how to redefine my addEntity function.